# How to apply disabled style of ASP.net dropdownlist

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

Suppose that I have a dropdownlist in ASP.net like that:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddOwnershipDocumentType" class="msbdd" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the definition of msdbdd:

```
.msbdd {
    font-family: WMitraBold;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: right !important;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

I'm trying to apply style to this dropdownlist whenever its disabled. I tried `.msbdd select[disabled]`, `.msbdd select:disabled` , `.msbdd select[readonly]`, `.msbdd select:read-only` but none of them Worked (in Chrome).

How can I achieve selecting a disabled dropdownlist in CSS?

Comment: is it disabled from code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddOwnershipDocumentType" class="msbdd" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

to

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddOwnershipDocumentType" CssClass="msbdd" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

class to **Css**Class, your code should look like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bronni/ar1qoznj/6/).

Then you can select / style them with `select.msbdd:disabled`.

See [Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bronni/ar1qoznj/6/) on fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddOwnershipDocumentType" CssClass="msbdd" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Note the `CssClass` attribute instead of the `class` attribute.

CSS:

```
select[disabled].msbdd {
    font-family: WMitraBold;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: right !important;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```